# Laravel check if relation is empty

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have an object with some relationships and I need to check if these relations are empty or not, I'm trying to check with is_null, isset, != undefined, etc but nothing works, here is the relationship I get when it's empty :

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#197 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
    array(0) {
  }
}
```

Is there a way to check this easily ?
Thanks.

Comment: $model->relation()->exists()

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this.

**#1** In the query itself, you can filter models that do not have any related items:

```
Model::has('posts')->get()
```

**#2** Once you have a model, if you already have loaded the collection (which below #4 checks), you can call the `count()` method of the collection:

```
$model->posts->count();
```

**#3** If you want to check without loading the relation, you can run a query on the relation:

```
$model->posts()->exists()
```

**#4** If you want to check if the collection was eager loaded or not:

```
if ($model->relationLoaded('posts')) {
    // Use the collection, like #2 does...
}
```

**Note:** Replace `posts` with the name of your relationship in the above examples.

Comment: Relation is the name of your relationship in this, not a literal relation method.

Answer (score 23):

If model already have loaded relationship, you can determine the variable is `null` or call `isEmpty()` to check related items:

```
// For one relation:
if ( $model->relation ) {
    // ...
} else {
    // $model->relation is null
}

// For many relations:
if ( $model->relation->isEmpty() ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: $model->relation->isEmpty() is the defined answer to this question.

Comment: This is the correct answer, `$model->relation()->exists()` runs another query, even with eager loaded results.

Comment: If on one relation has deleted_at filled, the value will be `null` , so exists() and isEmpty() will not work.

Answer (score 11):

First, you might want to check if your `Relation` is loaded

```
if ($user->relationLoaded('posts'))...
```

second, when it is loaded, you might want to see if it is an empty `Collection` or `Null`,

```
if ($user->posts()->exists())...
```

PS

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Model::has('relation')->get();
Model::doesntHave('relation')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $model->relation()->exists()
if (count($model->relation))
{
  // check exists
}
```

also 
2nd method

```
if(!is_null($model->relation)) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: I already try the second method with my relation (is_null($experiment->tm())) but this doesn't work too :/ and the first one returns me nothing :/

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but you can use Laravel's `optional` helper to call methods on a relationship you suspect might not have a value:

```
optional($user->comments)->where('is_popular', true);
```

If the user doesn't have comments, this will return null. Otherwise it will return the user's popular comments.

Comment: I think it will return an empty collection, not Null

Answer (score 1):

If the relation is not always empty, way more clear way is to use Laravel build-in helper 'optional'

For example, this code will not throw an error if the relation is null

```
  {{ optional($this->category)->name }}
```